# select option with icon which when clicked will call separate function and preventdefault

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

I have a select drop down from **antd** to select the users from a list. I need an icon (favorite) prefixed to their name so that I have the ability to favorite them so that they appear on the top of the list. Clicking on the name should select the option and clicking on the icon should call an API and should not select that option. How do I prevent default from that function?

[image: Looks like this]https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVZev.jpg

```
<Select optionFilterProp='children' value={this.state.selectedUserId}
onSelect={this.handleChangeUser.bind(this)}
className='mb-10 w-100' 
>
    <Option value={'0'} key={'0'}>
        Choose User
    </Option>
    {this.state.userData && this.state.userData.length !== 0                                             
    ? this.state.userData.map(user => (                                                  
      <Option key={user.id.toString()} value={user.id}>                                                      
        <Icon                                                            
            type='star'
            theme={user.isFavorite ? 'filled' : 'outlined'}
            style={{
              margin: '4px 10px 0px 0px',
              color: user.isFavorite ? 'green' : '',
            }}
            onClick={() => this.handleChangeFavoriteUsers(user.id)}
        />
      {user.informal_name}
    </Option>
   ))
   : ''}
</Select>
```

Icon click handler

```
public async handleChangeFavoriteUsers(value: string) {
  // Call API to update the User and prevent default
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by changing to

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleChangeFavoriteUsers(user.id, e.stopPropagation())}
```